# Merging three keras models depending one output of one

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, model, tensorflow2.0

I want to create a network that takes the input and depending on the output value(0 or 1) I want to direct the prediction two the two different models.
The models will be the age prediction systems however, I want to classify gender and then depending on the prediction of gender network, I predict male's age or female's age. In addition I also want to see the accuracy of the whole model as one.

```
A1 = layers.Input(shape=pca.shape[1], name='gender_input')
A2 = layers.Dense(512, activation='relu')(A1)
A3 = layers.Dropout(0.5)(A2)
A4 = layers.Dense(1024, activation='relu')(A3)
A5 = layers.Dropout(0.5)(A4)
A6 = layers.Dense(1024, activation='relu')(A5)
A7 = layers.Dropout(0.4)(A6)
A8 = layers.Dense(256, activation='relu')(A7)
A9 = layers.Dropout(0.1)(A8)
A10 = layers.Dense(1, activation='softmax')(A9)

B2 = layers.Dense(512, activation='relu')(A10)
B3 = layers.Dropout(0.5)(B2)
B4 = layers.Dense(1024, activation='relu')(B3)
B5 = layers.Dropout(0.5)(B4)
B6 = layers.Dense(1024, activation='relu')(B5)
B7 = layers.Dropout(0.4)(B6)
B8 = layers.Dense(256, activation='relu')(B7)
B9 = layers.Dropout(0.1)(B8)
B10 = layers.Dense(8, activation='softmax')(B9)

C2 = layers.Dense(512, activation='relu')(A10)
C3 = layers.Dropout(0.5)(C2)
C4 = layers.Dense(1024, activation='relu')(C3)
C5 = layers.Dropout(0.5)(C4)
C6 = layers.Dense(1024, activation='relu')(C5)
C7 = layers.Dropout(0.4)(C6)
C8 = layers.Dense(256, activation='relu')(C7)
C9 = layers.Dropout(0.1)(C8)
C10 = layers.Dense(8, activation='softmax')(C9)
```

[Aim](https://i.stack.imgur.com/d006d.png)

Comment: Why don't you predict them jointly? Then the ML model will be able to learn from a richer source of info, and the model will be less complicated.

Comment: I did that. This is for research purposes. I need to try 3 to 4 models.

Comment: This won't work, because you are producing a singular gender value and then using a large network to predict age from this value. If you are predicting age from a single (unrelated) value, you will not have enough info to accurately predict because the mdoel can only read so much into this value. Once, you've fixed this issue, look at http://man.hubwiz.com/docset/TensorFlow.docset/Contents/Resources/Documents/api_docs/python/tf/keras/backend/switch.html